# Hibernate + Spring LocalSessionFactory update query exequte properly but no change saved in database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
package com.kk.mypackage;
@Repository
@Transactional public class DBConnectionCredit implements DBConnectionCreditInt {

    @Autowired
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void insertEmailSaveRequest(EmailSaveRequest emailSaveRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder sbCover=new StringBuilder();
            sbCover.append("UPDATE QCIB_EMAIL_SAVE_REQ SET ");
            sbCover.append("CORELATIONID='12345' ");
            sbCover.append(" WHERE SID='412'");


            int i=sessionFactory.getObject().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sbCover.toString()).executeUpdate();

            System.out.println(" i= "+i+" data saved : "+sbCover);

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Console :**

```
Hibernate: UPDATE QCIB_EMAIL_SAVE_REQ SET CORELATIONID='12345'  WHERE SID='412'

i= 0 data saved : UPDATE QCIB_EMAIL_SAVE_REQ SET CORELATIONID='12345'  WHERE SID='412'
```

Comment: executeUpdate() returns 0. So no row was updated. So there is no row with SID = '412' to update. Some notes: Why use a deprecated createSQLQuery() method? Why use a query in the first place instead of just getting the entity by ID and modifying it? Why use a StringBuilder for a purely static SQL string? And most importantly: why catch and ignore Exception. All these are bad practices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You should check session is opened. I guess you didn't open session.
2. You can be autowire EntityManager then unwrap Session object.